# MySQL, Python "CREATE" error:_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064

Tags: python, mysql

i am getting the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./CREATE.py", line 13, in 
    **cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, FirstName VARCHAR(25), LastName VARCHAR(25), Email VARCHAR (25), FlightNo. INT)")**
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
**_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT)' at line 1")**
```

I am very confused and not sure what i need to change. can anyone please assist. the python script to create the table is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'Team3', 'TestDB');

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SET sql_notes = 0; ")
    #cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, FirstName VARCHAR(25), LastName VARCHAR(25), Email VARCHAR (25), FlightNo. INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Jim', 'Bo','JIMBO@email.com, '2829922')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlighNo.) VALUES('Kevin', 'Wilkinison', 'KevinWilkinson@email.com', '3773827')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Osei', 'Seraphin','OseiSeraphin@email.com', '8171882')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Nicholas', 'Alexander', 'NicholasAlexander@email.com', '2625554')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Lejaney', 'Blue', 'LejaneyBlue@email.com', '0099884')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Brandon', 'Crandall', 'BrandonCrandall@email.com', '8833736')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Lola', 'Obasa', 'LolaObasa@email.com', '6657588')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Bob', 'Pizza', 'BobPizza@email.com', '3938722')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('John', 'Doe', 'JohnDoe@email.com', '3345223')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Email, FlightNo.) VALUES('Lisa', 'Ray', 'LisaRay@email.com', '7677584')")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, FirstName VARCHAR(25), LastName VARCHAR(25), Email VARCHAR (25), FlightNo. INT)"
```

### It becomes (better visualized I mean)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test
(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
FirstName VARCHAR(25), 
LastName VARCHAR(25), 
Email VARCHAR (25), 
FlightNo. INT)
```

And it has a period (.) after FlightNo

Remove it

Comment: Thanks @Drew, your comment was helpful.  Deleting my answer.

Comment: Just thought you'd like to know @dstudeba, didn't mean to chase you away !

Comment: No worries @Drew, education is always appreciated!